# Is it possible to upload new apps to Google Play Store programatically?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Is there a way to upload new apps to Google Play Console programatically?

I have already used triplet: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher

And Fastlane: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_play_store/

To upload new versions of apps that are already uploaded to Google Play Console.

Since I upload new versions AND initial version of new apps, I'd like to know is there's a way to automate upload of new apps.
Both fastlane and triplet requires, at least, one previous version already upload manually to play store.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, it's possible.

Google Play provides the Publishing API for that exact purpose: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher

To make it simpler, some client libraries in Java and Python have been provided as well, with usage examples: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries